# Parse Push Notification with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have an application where you log in and it gives you a user ID with parse. I then have a script to send a push notification to a custom channel based on that user ID (userid_their unique ID).  All of this is in javascript and I am going to package my app with phonegap. How can I get the actual app to receive the push based on the custom channel?

Thanks!

Comment: Parse does not currently support native push with Phonegap.

Comment: I know that Fosco, I'm asking if there is a way to get around this though with a plugin or Objective C itself?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Plugin for this, have a look at [this Push-plugin](https://github.com/francimedia/PushPlugin/blob/feature/parse/README-parse.md)(iOS only) or [that](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) for Android and iOS.

Also be sure to check out Raymond Camden's [blog post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/10/10/PhoneGap-Parsecom-and-Push-Notifications) about Parse.com with Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be use a native plugin, as qefzec has pointed out.

Another approach would be send the data to your server using ajax and then use Parse's restful API to transmit the data. You have to use their queries to make sure you are updating the correct installation or object.